# How to add the PayPal Smart Payment Buttons to my forms.py

Tags: python, django, paypal

Helloo,

I am finding difficultly in proceeding with adding the PayPal smart payment buttons in my forms. In my project, there are forms to choose the required payment method through selecting Radio Button Stripe or Paypal.

I don't know how to arrange it so that the logos of credit cards and PP used in this website to be shown in the check out page:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/radio

The stripe payment method is working perfectly fine I just want to add the PayPal payment option.

This is how my project is arranged:
Forms.py

```
PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Stripe'),
    ('P', 'Paypal')
)

class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
----address related forms-----------------------------------
    payment_option = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES)
```

here is the checkout template:

```
              <h3>Payment option</h3>

              <div class="d-block my-3">
                {% for value, name in form.fields.payment_option.choices %}
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <input id="{{ name }}" name="payment_option" value="{{ value }}" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</label>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
```

Here is the views.py

```
class CheckoutView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            form = CheckoutForm()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'couponform': CouponForm(),
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': True
            }
-----------------Shipping address codes-----------------------------

                payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')

                if payment_option == 'S':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='stripe')
                elif payment_option == 'P':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='paypal')
                else:
                    messages.warning(
                        self.request, "Invalid payment option selected")
                    return redirect('core:checkout')

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
```

Here is the models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I need help to integrate the PayPal payment in my checkout page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't incorporating any of the sample JS from https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/radio , and are instead using django forms radio buttons

If you want to use the card logos from there, you have to at least incorporate the asset `card-mark.png` when the card option is selected

And you have to include a mechanism for the PayPal button to be revealed when the PayPal option is selected. I don't see any PayPal button rendering code in your code that you shared, so you need to add it

Comment: Where should i be adding them in the forms.py or the html template ?

Comment: The template, most likely.